# search entire document instead of by line php

Tags: php, string, file-listing

Ok, so I'm trying to list text files in PHP and I need them to contain any number of one variable `$words_to_match ='spaghetti'` and echo the link. As you can see, the text files are full of strings (or is one string each).

Here is my code:

```
if($_POST["Confirmed"]=='') 
{
    echo "You need to enter something to search!";
}
else
{
    $path_to_check = 'Confirmed/';
    $words_to_match = $_POST["Confirmed"];//Checks the form from the last page 

    foreach(glob($path_to_check.'*.txt') as $filename)
        {
            foreach(file($filename) as $fli=>$fl) // Not sure what to put here.
                {
                    if (stristr($fl,$words_to_match) !== false) //Or here.
                    {
                        echo '<a href="'.$filename.'">'.$filename.'</a><br />';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I'm not sure what to put in the spot that says `foreach(file($filename) as $fli=>$fl)` Or `if (stristr($fl,$words_to_match) !== false)`. I'm pretty sure the second one is right.
When I search for a file containing several lines of `spaghetti`, it shows several of the same file. If there are 3 lines of `spaghetti`, there are 3 files -- etc. I just want one of that file listed, even if there is a whole pile of `spaghetti` in that file. My theory is that it reads the  file line by line, and gives an output of all of the lines that have `spaghetti` in them.

To recap, I want to make it so I have one listed file instead of how many lines contain a string listed as a file.

Any ideas?

BTW, I'm using a standard GoDaddy hosting account with PHP 5.3.

Comment: `$words_to_check` != `$words_to_match`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just:

```
foreach(glob(...) as $filename) {
    if( stripos(file_get_contents($filename),$words_to_check) !== false) {
        // word is present.
    }
}
```

Comment: WOW... I had never thought of that. And thanks for responding so fast! It worked. I tested it right away and it is now in place on my webpage! Thanks again!